# How to toggle between light theme and dark theme in highlightjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, syntax-highlighting

I am working on a NextJS application with highlightjs to highlight code blocks. In my application, I have a dark mode and light mode. Now, how do we switch between dark and mode programmatically?

I am currently highlighting using highlightAll() method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add Dark and Light Mode Styles:
style.css

```
/* Light Mode */
.light-mode {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

/* Dark Mode */
.dark-mode {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

A Component example for switching between light and darkmode.

```
// Your component file

import { useState } from 'react';
import hljs from 'highlight.js';
import 'highlight.js/styles/github.css'; // Default theme, choose a light one
import 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark.css'; // Dark theme from Highlight.js

const CodeHighlighter = () => {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const toggleMode = () => {
    setIsDarkMode(!isDarkMode);
    highlightCode();
  };

  const highlightCode = () => {
    const codeBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('pre code');
    hljs.highlightAll();

    // Load corresponding theme based on mode
    const themePath = isDarkMode ? 'highlight.js/styles/github-dark.css' : 'highlight.js/styles/github.css';
    loadTheme(themePath);
  };

  const loadTheme = (path) => {
    const existingTheme = document.querySelector('#highlight-theme');
    if (existingTheme) {
      existingTheme.href = path;
    } else {
      const theme = document.createElement('link');
      theme.rel = 'stylesheet';
      theme.id = 'highlight-theme';
      theme.href = path;
      document.head.appendChild(theme);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleMode}>Toggle Mode</button>
      <pre>
        <code className="javascript">
          {`const example = () => {
            // Your code here
          };`}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CodeHighlighter;
```

Comment: But this won't use the highlightjs dark theme right? Above solution will just allow us to add few custom style.

Comment: You're correct, and I apologize for any confusion. If you want to switch between the built-in dark and light themes provided by Highlight.js, you can dynamically load the corresponding style sheets based on your dark/light mode.

Comment: Right, but how do we do that?

Comment: Updated the answer, now it will switch between unbuilt dark and light themes. And  ignore CSS style.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution doesn't work. It just stay with last updated style sheet.